# How can I build the WAR file for pentaho-platform from GitHub sources?

Tags: ant, war, pentaho

I have been able to "easily" create a Tomcat-ready Pentaho BI instance from the [GitHub repo of pentaho-platform](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-platform) with:

```
$ ant -f dev-build.xml dev_rebuild
```

This results in the directory `assembly/bin/stage/biserver-ce/tomcat` being created, whose server container can be started with

```
$ sh assembly/bin/stage/biserver-ce/start-pentaho.sh
```

For deployment, I could just copy the whole tomcat directory, but I feel that the proper way to deploy Pentaho BI would be to put the WAR file into an existing Tomcat installation.

So I wonder how can I create the WAR file and if there are any other requirements or configurations to take into account in order to make the Pentaho BI work like this.

I tried following the [Pentaho infocenter guide to build the server WAR](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help48/index.jsp?topic=%2Finstall_manual%2Ftask_deploying_tomcat6.html) but it didn't help (the steps listed there report a `BUILD SUCCESSFULL` but accomplish actually nothing, i.e. they behave just like the option `-projecthelp` does).

Would it be correct to create the WAR from the tomcat instance? I also tried this and almost succeeded: I had to copy some other files: `pentaho-solutions`, `pentaho-style` and do some other tweakings, but ended up with some errors regarding the Lucene query handler.

Any help will be appreciated.